# Viewing repository information from within Eclipse, when code was checked out using svn tortoise

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-2

I am using svn tortoise to checkout a maven project from a repository, I then open eclispe, and use the m2eclipse plugin to import a maven project. The maven projeect comes in okay, and I can build it fine.

The problem is that eclipse using subversive,  isn't marking files/ resources as being in source control (even though I seem to have all the relevant .svn directories.)

I get the same behaviour if I try and check the code in using
-> import -> check out Maven Projects from SCM. ie the project imports okay, but the files aren't linked in to teh svn repository in eclipse.

Are there any suggestions as to how I might proceed, as I find the tortoise svn checkin process pretty painful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up your project for team sharing (right click on project->Team->Share project)? If I remember correctly that should detect the existing .svn folders an enables version control inside of eclipse.

Comment: I concur : if you create the right repository location it should detect the .svn folders and offer to attach the project to the location

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try using [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).  It's the Eclipse plug-in for Subversion and is really good. I've also found that interacting with a SVN repository with Tortoise while also having Eclipse open and accessing the same repository causes problems.  You should avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend making sure that you commit using tortoise svn as I've had particularly spotty consistency with subclipse.  If you do you in/out with tortoise, and then just update with subclipse you should be fine.